# Validator function getting fired twice in textfield

Tags: forms, validation, extjs, textfield, extjs4.1

Following code uses validator config of textfield in ExtJs:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Simple Form',
        width: 350,
        url: 'save-form.php',
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%'
        },
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            validateOnBlur:true,//calling validator on blur
            validateOnChange:false,//not calling validator on change
            validator:function(){
                console.log('in validator');//printing to console whenever validator is called
                return true;
            }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

In the code, validateOnBlur is set to true where as validateOnChange is set to false.

The issue is that when user focusses the field for the first time and blurs out, then the validator function gets fired twice as shown in the screenshot attached.

If the user agains focusses the field second time, and blurs, then the validator gets fired only one and same is true for all the subsequent such actions.

But for the first time, when user focusses the field and blurs (either by mouse click or tab out) then the validator function gets fired twice.

Could anyone guide that what can be the possible reason behind this and how can this be stopped or is this a bug in version 4.1 of ExtJs?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It also happens in Version: 6.0.0.640 Build date: 2015-06-28

Answer (score 0):

i think this will solve your issue...Blur works differently..you can use blur instead of change and see what happens and what do  you want

```
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
    validateOnBlur: true, 
    listeners: {
        change: function (){
            console.log('in validator');
            return true;
        }
    }
}]
```